# Google Sheet webapp: Display a button programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am trying to display a button under certain condition on my HTML output

I succesfully wrote the code like this:

```
      <?
        var HTMLToDisplay = "";
        if (data[i][5] == 0) {
          HTMLToDisplay = ""
        } else {
          HTMLToDisplay = '<input type="button" value="Réserver" onclick="openForm(' + "'" + new Date(data[i][4]).toLocaleDateString('fr-BE', options) + "'" + ",'" + data[i][3] + "'," + data[i][0] + ')" />'
        } 
      ?>
                    
      <?= HTMLToDisplay ?>
```

But unfortunately, the HTML code appears in plain text rather than in the code

[image]

In fact the script automatically added some unwanted double quotes

[image]

Any idea how I can display my button just by code, without doing complex stuff?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The first image showing rendered HTML suggests that the quotes are missing from certain arguments in the inline function call - `workshop debutants` should be quoted too  I would suggest?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius You are definitely right, that was a mistake. I fixed it and update my post, but this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, please modify as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
<?= HTMLToDisplay ?>
```

#### To:

```
<?!= HTMLToDisplay ?>
```

By this, if the value of `HTMLToDisplay` is the valid HTML tag, the value of `HTMLToDisplay` put as the raw string. When it is loaded by the browser, it is shown as a button. If no button is shown, please check the value of `HTMLToDisplay` again.

#### Reference:

- [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

Comment: @Waza_Be Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As additional information, in the recent benchmark, it was found that when "loop" is used in the HTML template, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17) Although this might be resolved in the future update, in the current stage, when the HTML tags are created in Google Apps Script side and put it into the HTML without the loop, the process cost becomes low. If the size of `data` is large, please test it.